# OAuthConsumer framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, oauth

I actually work on iphone project, and i want to use OAuthConsumer for the authentification.
The developer guide say

"*In order to use the framework, you must first get a copy from the svn repository and compile it. Compiling the framework will automatically run all of the unit tests.*"

I get the svn repository but i don't understand how to compile this...

can you help me please ?

(sorry for my english...)

Thanks

ps: link to the installation guide http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have probably sorted this out already but in case it helps someone else...
http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer-iphone/

This project contains a makefile which will extract the Objective-C component of OAuthConsumer so that it is amenable for iPhone app development.

:)

Comment: yes, it's exactly what i used, thanks and hope your answer will be helpful for other